# Vuex module namespace not found in mapActions()

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm getting the following error while trying to call an action from my store:

> [vuex] module namespace not found in mapActions():
>   feedbacksessionStore/

From other solutions that I found online people were suggesting to set 'namespaced: true', however it doesn't help for my case somehow.

Here is the snippet of my store code:

```
export const feedbackSessionStore = {
    namespaced: true,

    state: {
        feedback_sessions: {},
    },

    actions: {

        async createFeedbackSession({commit, state}, { data }) {
          // some code
        }
    }
}
```

And the snippet of the component code:

```
import { mapGetters, mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex'

// some code

export default {
  name: 'create-edit-feedback-session',
  methods: {
    ...mapActions('feedbackSessionStore', [
        'createFeedbackSession'
    ]),
    // some code
}
```

Comment: did you register it? Like add it to the store?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a solution to this problem you have to do tow things:

1. make a 'feedbackSessionStore.js' as a separate module by doing this code in store/modules directory:

   ```
   namespaced: true,

   state: {
       feedback_sessions: {},
   },

   actions: {

       async createFeedbackSession({commit, state}, { data }) {
         // some code
       }
   }
   ```
2. add this module to the store/index.js like that:

   ```
   import * as feedbackSessionStore from "@/store/modules/feedbackSessionStore.js";
   ```

after these two steps it should work.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to El-Hani's answer, inside your store folder there must be an index.js file which contains your store modules. In that file import the module and register it.

```
// store/index.js
import 'feedbackSessionStore' from './modules/feedbackSessionStore.js'
    
Vue.use(Vuex)
    
export default new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
        feedbackSessionStore // <- Register here, and mapAction name becomes this
    }
}
```

And check if the pointed mapAction name is exactly the same with here.